# OS X Mountain Lion - make windows "Always on Top"

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Searching online, I can only find references to Afloat, which doesn't seem to work on Mountain Lion. Surely something like this must exist?

Answer (score 3):

The site doesn't list compatibility with Mountain Lion, but it's been working fine for me.

Comment: Looks like it works with TextMate, but not with Finder, Chrome or Excel. So it's not helping me very much.

Comment: Working with TextMate, Finder, Chrome and Excel here. It might be a SIMBL problem; maybe try reinstalling that. Do any other SIMBL extensions work?